# How to dynamically add floodlight tag

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am trying to dynamically add a floodlight tag to my page. This page is used by several different companies so we have implemented dynamically adding tracking and analytics so each company can add their own tracking.

I have a div: `<div id="bodyTrackingCode"></div>` which is right below the body opening tag.

I use .html to insert the tracking codes: $('#bodyTrackingCode').html(Info.BodyTracking);

This works great for all types of google analytics code. Unfortunately, I am having an issue with the floodlight tag. I believe it is because of the "document.write" in the code.

The code looks like this:

```
<!-- Start of DoubleClick Floodlight Tag: Please do not remove Activity name of this tag: xxxxxx to Call-Landing URL of the webpage where the tag is expected to be placed: xxxxxxx This tag must be placed between the <body> and </body> tags, as close as possible to the opening tag. Creation Date: 05/01/2018 --> <script type="text/javascript"> var axel = Math.random() + ""; var a = axel * 10000000000000; document.write('<iframe src="https://3948978.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=xxxxxxx;type=hea-l0;cat=jj-he0;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>'); </script> <noscript> <iframe src="https://3948978.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=xxxxxxx;type=hea-l0;cat=jj-he0;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;ord=1?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe> </noscript> <!-- End of DoubleClick Floodlight Tag: Please do not remove -->
```

I have tried escaping the end iframe tag and the end script tag. It gives me a console error of syntax error unexpected token <

When I escape the tags the page loads. If I don't escape the tag, the page is a big white screen. I suspect the document.write is replacing the body code.

I have no idea how to get this to work correctly. Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have document.write you cannot control, you can do this if you insert this before the script is loaded:

```
var myWrite = document.write, myWriteLN=document.writeln, dbhtml;
document.write=function(str) {
  dbhtml += str;
}
$(function() {
  $('#bodyTrackingCode').html(dbhtml);
});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the original tracking code. I posted a code I edited. Made the correction. The tracking code is coming from a database and being dynamically inserted onto the page.

Comment: Thank you so much mplungjan! that looks like it fixed it!!

Comment: so when using the code, the tracking code is not working.

Comment: No console errors. This is my code: dbhtml = Info.BodyTracking;
            var myWrite = document.write, myWriteLN=document.writeln, dbhtml;
            document.write=function(str) {
                dbhtml += str;
            }
            $(function () {
                $('#bodyTrackingCode').html(dbhtml);
            });

Comment: It seems like the document.write isn't firing.

Comment: Try console.log in the replacement function

Comment: Ok. It wrote out the code above. No errors. Not sure what I am looking for in the console.log...

Comment: `document.write=function(str) {
  console.log(str);
  dbhtml += str;
}`

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` will only add some content to the html when it is executed on page load. If the page has already loaded then `document.write` will replace the whole html by what is written, see the description here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

Since you are adding the code with `jQuery` after the page is loaded, you can replace the `document.write(...` with

```
jQuery('body').append(...
```

or

```
jQuery('#bodyTrackingCode').append(...
```